# SSRS Reports are timing out on Production server ?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

We are using SSRS 2008 for report development and then deploy all reports on Sharepoint site. We are facing an issue with SSRS reports are timing out on production server.  They are runnning fine on test server, integration server and UAT server.  (under 3 minutes).  On production Sharepoint site they are taking more than 10 minutes.

- I have checked indexes on UAT and Prod, they are upto date and underlying DDL for both environemnt is same.
- Stats are upto date.
- Data volumn is also same on both server. 
  I couldn't figure out, why they are timing out on prod server ?

Comment: Have you checked [ExecutionLog2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2009/01/05/executionlog2-view.aspx) yet to see which part of processing is your bottleneck?

Comment: I would also take a step back and use SQL Profiler to verify that the performance of the underlying dataset queries is the same on all 3 servers.

Comment: Check the execution plans of the queries on each server too.